# Connecting Node.js with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am new to react and am working on my first project, I have a question on how to connect react with node.js.I have a post page where you can post data and I want to get that data in node.js so that I can connect it with MongoDB.

Here's my code

**Post component**

```
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faPlus } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import "./componentStyles/postStyles.css";

const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />;

function Post() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Post your data here</h2>
      <form className="post-form">
        <input className="inputTitle" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
        <textarea
          className="inputContent"
          name="content"
          placeholder="Content"
          rows="3"
        />
        <input
          className="inputTitle"
          name="contact"
          placeholder="contact details"
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label className="inputTitle" for="CompanyType">
          Company Type:{" "}
        </label>
        <select>
          <option value="AI">AI</option>
          <option value="Stocks">Stocks</option>
          <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
          <option value="Medical">Medical</option>
          <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
          <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
        </select>
        <button className="submitBtn">{element}</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

**Post page**

```
import React from "react";
import Post from "../components/Post";

const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: "90vh",
      }}
    >
      <Post />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Thanks in advance for Answers

Comment: https://fullstackopen.com/en/part3/node_js_and_express follow this track, very detailed and hands on

Comment: React is a front-end UI tool. Node.js is a backend server tool. I have had success using Express.js as a backend server running under Node.js using it to serve up a React SPA. You can also incorporate a backend API that your front-end client app (React) uses to interact with your mongo database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not one "standard" way of doing this. There are several ways to do it, such as:

- using redux and redux middlewares like `redux-saga` and `redux-thunk`
- with hooks ([`react-query`](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query) is worth looking at)
- with a simple abstract API manager
- directly inside the component (not recommended)

Anyway, React is JavaScript at the end of the day, so you need a client to make HTTP requests to the API. Many use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

A pseudo code example:

```
// APIManager.js
export const getPosts = () => {
  return axios.get(`${baseUrl}/posts`).then(resp => resp.data);
};

// Post.jsx
const Post = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    APIManager.getPosts().then(res => setPosts(res));
  }, []);
};
```

Also, there are many other client libraries that you can use for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to set up a nodejs environment.
2. Add Express or Koa to handle requests.
3. Add Mongodb -> use mongo atlas and add the end point to the backend. Make sure to configure your Mongodb Atlas environment to handle requests.
4. Add the routes that you want to your backend to handle the data exchanges.
5. Use Fetch or Axios on the front end to get, post, put, delete data.

There are courses and articles that cover this more in detail. I suggest checking them out, because you will need to understand some of nuances that are specific for your use case, such as working with mongodb. This post could be turned into a book, but I just wanted to help guide you in the right direction.